# How to add image with address in hashmap?

Tags: java, android, slideshow

I want to add image from drawalbe in hashmap please help me.

Below is code what I am trying:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_description);


    setupSlider();
}

private void setupSlider()
{
    mSlider = findViewById(R.id.description_slider);

    HashMap<String, String> url_maps = new HashMap<>();
    url_maps.put("Ramos", R.drawable.images+"");
    url_maps.put("Abbas", R.drawable.ramos +"");

}
}
```

Comment: You can add whatever in a hashmap, but you must know what do you want to put in it and how are you going to retrieve it. So if you want to store the resource reference then is <String, Integer>, if you want to stire tye drawable resulting of fetching a resource then it should be <String, Drawable> and you must convert the resource to a drawable first, etc. Why do you want to store the resource reference as a string in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because type of (R.id.images) is int, you should better put them in `HashMap<String, Integer>`

more infomation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.id

```
 private void setupSlider()
{
    mSlider = findViewById(R.id.description_slider);

    HashMap<String, Integer> url_maps = new HashMap<>();
    url_maps.put("Ramos", R.drawable.images);
    url_maps.put("Abbas", R.drawable.ramos);

}
```